# Cannot access mounted volume in docker container

Tags: linux, docker, chown, node.js, container

I download latest node images from docker, and try to run a container with the following command:

```
$ sudo docker run -it -v $(pwd)/app:/home/node/app --name node node /bin/bash
```

Then the container was created and I get into the /home/node/app dir. I tried 'ls' command and get 'permission deny'.

I do search online, someone suggests change owner of app/ at the host to 1000. But it doesn't work.

Here is some information I think may be helpful:

```
$ id //at the host
uid=1000(qwang) gid=1000(qwang) groups=1000(qwang),10(wheel) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023

$ id //in the container 'node'
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
$ id node //in the container  'node'
uid=1000(node) gid=1000(node) groups=1000(node)

$ ls -al //pwd => /home/node
drwxr-xr-x. 3 node node   69 Jul 19 13:51 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root   18 Jul  8 04:16 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 node node  220 Nov  5  2016 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--. 1 node node 3515 Nov  5  2016 .bashrc
-rw-r--r--. 1 node node  675 Nov  5  2016 .profile
drwxrwxr-x. 2 node node 4096 Jul 19 13:50 app
```